# Creating smaller chunks from large file and sort the chunks

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am implementing external sort in python, and currently stuck with this problem. I have divided a large text file containing integer numbers into small chunks and I am trying to sort these chunks. So far I am able to write this much.

```
with open(fpath,'rb') as fin:
    input_iter = iter(lambda: fin.read(40 * 1024),'')
    for item in input_iter:
        print item
        current_chunk = list(item)
        # sort the buffers
        current_chunk.sort(key = lambda x : int(x))
```

When I execute this code, I got an error

```
File "problem3.py", line 68, in <lambda>
current_chunk.sort(key = lambda x : int(x))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

which I guess is coming due to this line `input_iter = iter(lambda: fin.read(40 * 1024),'')`
Is their an alternate way to over come this problem.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have whitespace in your input:

```
>>> int(' ')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
>>> int('\n')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
>>> int('\t')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Whitespace is stripped when converting to `int`, hence the confusing error message; note how there is *nothing* between the quotes in the exception message (Python 3 has fixed this).

Strip spaces:

```
current_chunk = filter(None, map(str.strip, item))
```

or avoid turning them to integers:

```
current_chunk.sort(key=lambda x: int(x) if x.strip() else x)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, butI checked the file it didnt have white spaces in it, it is '' (nothing in between the braces) which is causing the issue. We have to get around this ''

Comment: *Just* `filter(None, inputlist)` would get rid of empty values for you. **However**, the code you've shown us would never result in empty strings, whitespace (including newlines and tabs) would account for the error much better.